# Restrict tasks logged by user to a particular type

Tags: validation

We are required to restrict a particular profile from logging tasks on any other  object but the case object.
I see i can use what.type in apex code, but i am trying to evaluate use of a validation rule. I see there is a whatID but i cloud not use a starts with filter (CRUDE way)on the whatID. Please advise if anybody is aware of any different approach to solution this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you could use something like this in a validation rule:

```
LEFT(WhatId, 3) <> "500"
&&
$User.Profile_Name__c ="your_profile_name"
```

Source of object ids:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005995&language=en_US

Comment: Thank you, that worked, however i am not sure why BEGINS did not.Appreciate you taking the time to reply.